# Discord.py How to make bot not respond to PM's

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

As the title asks, is there a way for the bot to not work in PM's and only work when in used in channels?

What I have done at the moment is have this statement in front of my @client.command

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def profile(ctx):
    if ctx.message.server == None:
        pass
    else:
        # Code
```

Is there an easier way to go about doing this? I've read that I could use a global check for it, but I'm not sure how to implement that.

EDIT: I'm coding this using `Commands Extension`

Comment: That looks good to me; why do you think there would be a different way?

Comment: @AdamBarnes Since I have to add that for every command I create, I feel that repeating that line each time will make the code unnecessarily long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the [documentation](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord-api-events) that I could see which said anything about globally disabling events for private messages.

The way you've done it is exactly what I'd do.  You say you don't want to repeat the line every time, but you can only have one `on_message()`, so that line will only need to appear once; every command that needs to obey those rules will just be in that `if` block:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.server is not None:
        if message.content.startswith('!dice'):
            ...

        if message.content.startswith('!roulette'):
            ...
```

---

EDIT:  It appears you're using the `commands` extension, which is pretty much undocumented.

Reading the docstring for `Command`, though, I came across [this](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/1863a1c6636f53592519320a173ec9573c090c0b/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L109) section:

```
no_pm : bool
    If ``True``\, then the command is not allowed to be executed in
    private messages. Defaults to ``False``. Note that if it is executed
    in private messages, then :func:`on_command_error` and local error handlers
    are called with the :exc:`NoPrivateMessage` error.
```

So if you define your command as such:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True, no_pm=True)
async def profile(ctx):
    ...
```

It will be disabled in PMs.

Comment: Is this how you're supposed to implement commands? Through the @client.event and on_message, not with @client.command?

Comment: Ah.  I'm wondering if we're looking at different things...  Could you link me to documentation of `command`?  I [can't find anything](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=command&check_keywords=yes&area=default)...

Comment: The way I've coded my commands is similar to [this example](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/examples/basic_bot.py) in their GitHub examples.

Comment: I've edited my answer to reflect that you're using the `commands` extension, which I didn't previously know.  I'd appreciate if you could just add a line to your question saying that you're using it, or perhaps a larger snippet of your code - to help future Googlers.

Comment: `no_pm=True` did the trick! Thanks for your help! I wasn't aware that `@client.command` is part of extension, and I've updated my question now to include it.

Comment: Thank you; I've updated my answer to match your question's function name and signature.  Glad I could help.

Answer (score 5):

"no_pm = true" doesn't seem to work now.
so add "@commands.guild_only()" below @client.command()

example:

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def commandname():
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to code it with `@bot.event` you have to do it like so:

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('!dm')
        await message.author.send('Hi. This message is send in DM!')
```